# Is there any incentive to ordering my Steam Link and Steam Controller through the Steam Store?

Tags: steam, steam-link, steam-in-home-streaming

I have neither seen or used either of these new toys.  However, just the *possibility* of playing Civ while sprawled on the couch is an enticing $100 experiment.  My quandary is that these pieces of hardware are the same price on the Steam Store as they are on Amazon, but Amazon promises delivery in two days while Valve is asking me to be patient for a full week.  Is there **any** benefit to ordering through my profile on the Steam platform?

Comment: If there was, I'm sure Valve would advertise with it openly.

Comment: @Christian At this point I'm deciding between 3x points using my Amazon Visa, or being certain that the featured sales page knows that I already own the hardware and it will be advertised to me less.

Comment: I think the steamcontroler still comes with free games when you get on the steam page, but i'm not sure. and playing civ with the steam controler is leaps and bounds better then with something like an xbox controler

Comment: At checkout the Steam Store stuck me with $16 dollars in shipping (but no tax), while Amazon charged me $6 in sales tax but free 2-day shipping through Prime.  I went with the latter, so now the hard part is convincing my wife that I need to run a second cord _back_ in to the living room.

Comment: You should add your experience as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the region you live in it might come with one or more free games.
In the region I live in, the Steam controller and Steam link
are not available for buying through steam, but that doesn't stop Steam from
suggesting me to buy them every day. I'm guessing, and I cannot confirm this,
that if you buy yours through Steam, they'll register that somewhere and stop
nagging you about it.
*I wonder why Steam isn't programmed to detect that and stop nagging me*

Comment: Christmas of 2012 I did playtesting at Valve, they asked if I wanted to take a piece of clothing from this large merchandise closet.  I asked if instead could someone delete the beta invites from my Steam inventory.  A developer sat with me and tried his damnedest for the better part of half an hour but no luck.  Just in time for the trading cards the following summer (and the marketplace) you could finally delete items.